# How remember me is working on Laravel and Yii2?

Tags: yii2, laravel-5.3, remember-me

I have installed two different PHP frameworks **Laravel 5.3** and **Yii2 advanced**. Both frameworks provide authentication out of the box which is great.

And both have the checkbox `Remember me` on the login page.

In Laravel, I have found that there is a `remember_token` field on users table which is as per my understanding used for the remember me feature.

But there is no such extra field on Yii2's user table.

So, I guess both provides the same feature but working differently. So I want to know that how that feature is working on both the frameworks?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** I'm asking this because I have one system built with Yii2 and now I'm going to build a new system with Laravel. New Laravel system will use the same `user` table of the Yii2. Means the user can login into both the system with the same credentials.

Thanks,

Parth vora

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 have `auth_key` - its default name, but you can define ur own column name and then declare it in identity class, which implements yii\web\IdentityInterface, in function `getAuthKey()`.

Comment: Did you mean that "auth_key" field in Yii2 is the the same field as "remember_token" in Laravel?

Comment: That's right, here u have some docs: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

The `remember me` function in Yii 2 (and most php frameworks) makes use of cookie-based login.

From the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html#implementing-identity):

> `getAuthKey()` returns a key used to verify cookie-based login. The key is stored in the login cookie and will be later compared with the server-side version to make sure the login cookie is valid.

Yii uses the `auth_key` field by default. That's probably the same field as Laravel's `remember_token`.

How it works is as follows:

1. Login with the `remember me` field checked.
2. Yii sets a cookie containing the user's (serialized) `id`, `auth_key` and `duration` (amount of seconds representing the duration of validity for this cookie). In yii2, the cookie name is specified by the `identityCookie` array in the config (user component).
3. All guests' requests are checked for the existance of the cookie, if it exists and is valid, the user is logged in.

That's basicly how cookie based logins work, so I'm assuming that Laravel uses a similar, if not exact same implementation.